# Crispy burnt leaves on raspberry plant

Tags: diseases, raspberries

I have a handful of raspberry patches.

In one of the patches of cultivar *prelude* the plants are showing some black “crusting” around a small number of leaves, like they were burnt. The cane and other leaves look otherwise healthy. I also observe the canes producing fruit are shorter than usual. The first two pictures are of these raspberries.

I also have a thee purple raspberry plants. Two are very healthy, but one did not put on many buds this spring and now the leaves are also starting to looked “burnt” but to a much more severe level than the other patch. The last two pictures are of these raspberries.

I haven’t noticed blotchy canes on any raspberry plant.

Am I dealing with a disease or some sort of environmental factor? In either case, why actions can/should I be taking?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this info for what appears to be your general area? https://pnwhandbooks.org/plantdisease/host-disease/raspberry-rubus-spp-viruses

Answer (score 1):

Looks like anthracnose fungus on black raspberries. Years ago when I grew them there was no chemical control. Recommendations were to remove and dispose of infected canes and not to plant reds within 500 ft of black raspberries. Back then there were no purple raspberries. Prelude is listed as a red.